# SSL needed for Amazon cloudfront to use with CNAME

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cname

I want to use Amazon Cloudfront service for my S3 bucket. Also, i will use it with cname. For example http://cdn.mysite.com instead of blabla.cloudfront.com.

When i looked at cloudfront pricing i have seen that there is a 600 USD/Mo pricing for ssl certificate with cname. Should i absolutely pay this money because i don't need to use htttps, i will just use it like http://cdn.mysite.com.

Answer (score 3):

You won't need to pay the $600/month fee if you don't use a custom SSL certificate with `CloudFront`.

You can either not use SSL at all, or use their default SSL certificate by accessing the distribution as `<distribution-id>.cloudfront.net`

Comment: Thanks, but in distribution settings page it made me choose 'Default Cloudfront Certificate' as SSL certificate and i added a CName for my website (cdn.site.com) because i will use it instead of <distribution-id>.cloudfront.net. So, since i will not use it as https://cdn.site.com, i don't need to pay $600/Mo right? But if i wanted to use https:// for my cname i would pay it?

Comment: That's correct, if you want https:// on your custom CNAME, you would need to pay for the Custom SSL certificate. Otherwise, there's no need to pay for it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was confusing me :)

Answer (score 1):

CloudFront now works with [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/), which is considerably cheaper than your typical SSL cert, and a lot easier to manage.